# "ifelse" function for character in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to create a new column of religion (called "AR2") that will take the word from column "religion" and fit a specific number in the new column
Like, if it is "Christian" I want it will be "0" and if-else  "1"
So, this is the code I create:

```
sample.data$AR2<-(ifelse(sample.data$religion=="Christian",0,1))
```

But it creates a new column with only "1" and no "0" for Christian.

Someone can please help me to understand What I'm doing wrong??

Thank you so much,
Maya

Comment: could you provide `dput(head(sample.data$religion))`?

Comment: > dput(head(sample.data$religion))
c("Jewish", "Jewish", "Jewish", "Jewish", "Moslem", "Jewish")

Comment: Code seems go be working fine : `religion <- c("Jewish", "Christian", "Jewish", "Jewish", "Moslem", "Jewish");ifelse(religion == "Christian", 0, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be syntactic mistakes. Try this:

```
df$AR2 <- ifelse(df$religion == "Christian", 0, 1)
```

Result:

```
df 
   religion AR2
1 Christian   0
2    Muslim   1
3     Hindu   1
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  religion = c("Christian", "Muslim", "Hindu")
)
```

Comment: There was a trailing `/` in the original post; has now been removed

Comment: I would suggest to rollback the edit because this may create confusion

Comment: What exactly are the syntactic mistakes you think are here, without having any of the data?

Comment: See my comment above